# Spark: Nested Data Structures in dataframe Flatten

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to flatten a dataframe in order to join this with another dataframe in Spark (Scala).

Basically my 2 dataframes have got the following schemas:

DF1

```
root
|-- field1: string (nullable = true)
|-- field2: long (nullable = true)
|-- field3: long (nullable = true)
|-- field4: long (nullable = true)
|-- field5: integer (nullable = true)
|-- field6: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- field7: long (nullable = true)
|-- field8: long (nullable = true)
|-- field9: long (nullable = true)
|-- field10: integer (nullable = true)
```

DF2

```
root
|-- field1: long (nullable = true)
|-- field2: long (nullable = true)
|-- field3: string (nullable = true)
|-- field4: integer (nullable = true)
|-- field5: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- field6: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- field7: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- field8: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- field9: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- field10: integer (nullable = true)
|-- field11: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I honestly have no clue how I can flatten DF2. Finally I need to join the 2 dataframes on DF.field4 = DF2.field9

I'm using 2.1.0

My first thought was to use explode but that is already deprecated in Spark 2.1.0 Does anyone has a clue for me?

Comment: I think with Datasets you could use flatMap?

Comment: I guess you have to `explode` your arrays first, then join

Comment: THe explode functionality is deprecated in Spark 2.1.0

Comment: Does `DF2` have `case class` or can you share the creation of `df2'?

Comment: My mistake the explode functionality is still available in Spark 2.1.0 under functions.explode in the org.apache.spark.sql package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake the explode functionality is still available in Spark 2.1.0 under functions.explode in the org.apache.spark.sql package

Thanks

You can find the code below:

```
val DF2Exploded1 = DF2.select(DF2("*"), functions.explode(DF2("field5"))
                      .alias("field5_exploded"))

val DF2Exploded2 = DF2Exploded1.select(DF2Exploded1("*"), functions.explode(DF2Exploded1("field5_exploded.field8"))
                               .alias("field8_exploded"))
```

Comment: Hi Oliviervs, is there any way to avoid one explode per array and flatten the data frame in one nested operation?